# PHP - is there a way to change a function across the code with a compiler define

Tags: php

For example I have in my code many calls to function mysql_connect.

I want to change to mysqli_connect if PHP ver is 5.6 or more

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600) {
    define mysql_connect as mysqli_connect
}
```

Comment: you can use `function_exists()` to check if it is defined - and if not, write a wrapper. [which already has been done](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlwithmysqli/)

Comment: It would be far more productive to just fix your code.

Comment: Do you have to support both, or can you just search and replace mysql_connect with mysqli_connect?

Answer (score 0):

There are surely a lot of methods. None of them are nice tho. One clean way to do it is this:

```
function connect($params) {
    if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600) {
        mysqli_connect($params);
    } else {
        mysql_connect($params);
    }
}
```

That way, you just call the connect function and the function itself decides if it is to use `mysqli_connect()` or `mysql_connect()`

There is [`override_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) but honestly, that will just make your code pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly as hell, but might work for you

```
if (!function_exists("mysql_connect")) {
    function mysql_connect() {
        return call_user_func_array("mysqli_connect", func_get_args());
    }
}
```

Comment: What if they are both defined?

Comment: That probably won't work because `mysql_connect()` does exist until PHP 7.0. So mysqli_connect will never fire unless PHP 7.0 or higher is installed.

Comment: @AbraCadaver script will explode

Comment: @YUNOWORK that is true, `mysql_connect` was removed in PHP7, in PHP5.6 was only deprecated. But I don't think there is a way to redefine function without using `runkit` or `APD`